# Sourcing vimrc duplicates statusline in nvim

Tags: vimrc, neovim, statusline

I'm new to vim so I'm not sure if this is intended behavior or not, but it seems like a bug.

### Desired Behavior

After sourcing vimrc from within nvim, don't duplicate the contents of my statusline. Or at the very least, provide a way to reset my statusline.

### Bug Description

Whenever I do `:source ~/.vim/vimrc`, the contents of my statusline gets duplicated, like this:

[image: nvim statusline filename duplicated after sourcing vimrc]

If I source vimrc once I'll get `[No Name][No Name]`, if I source it again I get `[No Name][No Name][No Name]`, and so on. It doesn't reset until I quit and open nvim again.

### How to Reproduce Error

An example vimrc `~/.vim/vimrc_ex`:

```
set statusline+=%.35f
```

That's it. Now open with `nvim -u ~/.vim/vimrc_ex` and do `:source ~/.vim/vimrc_ex`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the `+=` operator, you actually ask vim to append some new values to the `statusline` variable. When you first open Vim `statusline` is set to an emtpy value so adding `%.35f` to it give you the expected behavior.

However when you source your config again, nothing empties the variable so you keep adding duplicate values to it. Thus you probably want to add

```
set statusline=
```

Before

```
set statusline+=%.35f
```

This way you initialize your statusline to an empty value every time you source your configuration and when you append new stuff to the variable with `+=` you don't create duplicates.